# HTTPS Web service call fails after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis-7.5

I do not have a lot of experience with deploying applications.

I have an ASP.Net Application from which I perform a call over HTTPS to a third party web service.  The webservice returns an xml string which I then parse on my side.  On my development environment, this works perfectly.  However, when I deploy the application (to a production VM), the webservice inexplicably does not return anything and my parsing step throws a null reference exception.

**More information on the production environment:**

1. I provisioned an Azure VM running Windows Server 2008, and published my application directly from Visual Studio 2013 to the VM.  I am hosting the application on IIS 7.5 within the DefaultAppPool.
2. I am able to browse the wsdl for the webservice via IE from the VM (via remote desktop connection)
3. I have tried installing the https certificate under trusted certificate authorities > local on the VM, and then ran IISRESET.
4. I have tried to turn off the firewall on the VM completely, but still the service call fails.
5. The third party service provider has confirmed that they are not seeing any traffic come through from my site.
6. When I run the application from my dev environment, but use the production databases, it still works, so it is definitely not an issue with my data **[UPDATE]**

The service call seems to be failing silently as the event log only lists the null reference exception, nothing specifically pertaining to the service call.

What am I missing?

### UPDATE:

```
 public void RunEnquiry(Client Client, string ResultType = "XPDF")
    {
        NormalSearch_Live_Service.NormalSearchServiceClient csClient = new NormalSearch_Live_Service.NormalSearchServiceClient();

        using (var db = new CreditBureauxDbContext())
        {
            // --== Step 1: Create the enquiry data-entities ==--
            var eb = new EnquiryBlock
            {
                CS_Data = "Y",
                CPA_Plus_NLR_Data = "N",
                Deeds_Data = "N",
                Directors_Data = "N",
                Identity_number = Client.Person.IDNumber.Truncate(13),
                Surname = Client.Person.Surname.Truncate(25),
                Forename = Client.Person.FullNames.Trim().Split(' ').Count() > 0 ? Client.Person.FullNames.Trim().Split(' ')[0].Truncate(15) : "",
                Forename2 = Client.Person.FullNames.Trim().Split(' ').Count() > 1 ? Client.Person.FullNames.Trim().Split(' ')[1].Truncate(15) : "",
                Forename3 = Client.Person.FullNames.Trim().Split(' ').Count() > 2 ? Client.Person.FullNames.Trim().Split(' ')[2].Truncate(15) : "",
                Gender = Client.Person.Gender.Truncate(1),
                Passport_flag = "N",
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(Client.Person.DateOfBirthUTC).ToString("yyyyMMdd"),
                Address1 = "",
                Address2 = "",
                Address3 = "",
                Address4 = "",
                PostalCode = "",
                HomeTelCode = "",
                HomeTelNo = "",
                WorkTelCode = "",
                WorkTelNo = "",
                CellTelNo = "",
                ResultType = ResultType,
                RunCodix = "N",
                Adrs_Mandatory = "N",
                Enq_Purpose = db.EnquiryPurposes.FirstOrDefault(ep => ep.Description.ToUpper().Contains("CREDIT ASSESSMENT")).Value,
                Run_CompuScore = "N",
                ClientConsent = "Y"
            };

            var enq = new Enquiry
            {
                pInput_Format = "XML",
                pOrigin = "CrediScan",
                pOrigin_Version = "1.0",
                pVersion = "1.0",
                Parameters = eb,
                RequestSent_TimestampUTC = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
            };

            using (var settings = new GlobalConfigDbContext())
            {
                // --== Step 2: Construct & perform service call ==--                
                var param = new NormalSearch_Live_Service.NormalEnqRequestParamsType
                {
                    pInput_Format = "XML",
                    pOrigin = "CrediScan",
                    pOrigin_Version = "1.0",
                    pUsrnme = settings.GetSettingValueAsString("Credit Check: PROD Username"),
                    pPasswrd = settings.GetSettingValueAsString("Credit Check: PROD Password"),
                    pVersion = "1.0",
                    pTransaction = String.Format("<Transactions>{0}</Transactions>", eb.ToXML())
                };

                var result = csClient.DoNormalEnquiry(param);

                // --== Step 3: Create enquiry result data-entities  ==--
                var er = new EnquiryResult
                {
                    ErrorCode = result.errorCode,
                    ErrorString = result.errorString,
                    TransactionCompleted = result.transactionCompleted,
                    RetData = result.retData
                };

                enq.EnquiryResult = er;

                Trace.TraceInformation("RETDATA" + Environment.NewLine + result.retData);

                var retDataDecoded = result.retData.DecodeBase64ToByteArray();

                if (!Encoding.UTF8.GetString(retDataDecoded, 0, 2).Equals("PK") || retDataDecoded.Length <= 5)
                    throw new FormatException("The data returned from CreditBureaux is not in the correct format or contains an error.");

                // --== Step 4: Save the query and validated results to database ==--
                try
                {
                    db.Enquiries.Add(enq);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbe)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError(dbe.ToString());
                    throw;
                }

                // --== Step 5: Parse the results ==--

                if (ResultType.Equals("XML"))
                {
                    if (!Encoding.UTF8.GetString(retDataDecoded, 0, 2).Equals("PK") || retDataDecoded.Length <= 5)
                        throw new FormatException("The data returned from CreditBureaux is not in the correct format or contains an error.");
                    Trace.TraceInformation("\n\n\n" + retDataDecoded.UnZipToMemoryList()[0].ReadToString() + "\n\n\n");
                }

                if (ResultType.Equals("XPDF"))
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("UNZIPPING PDF");
                    Trace.TraceInformation("RETDATA" + Environment.NewLine + result.retData);
                    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + retDataDecoded.UnZipToMemoryList()[0].ReadToString()); //Important!


                    var summaryItems = xmlDoc
                        .Root
                        .Element("EnqCC_ENQ_COUNTS")
                        .Element("ROW")
                       .Elements()
                       .Select(dn => new EnquirySummaryItem
                       {
                           Key = dn.Name.ToString(),
                           Value = dn.Value
                       })
                       .ToList();

                    var summary = new EnquirySummary
                    {
                        Enquiry_Id = xmlDoc.Root.Element("Enquiry_ID").Value,
                        EnquiryDate = xmlDoc.Root.Element("EnqCC_SRCHCRITERIA").Descendants("ENQ_DATE").ElementAt(0).Value,
                        EnquiryResult = enq.EnquiryResult,
                        SummaryItems = summaryItems
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        db.EnquirySummaries.Add(summary);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbe)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceError(dbe.ToString());
                        throw;
                    }


                    var directory = settings.GetSettingValueAsString("Document Management: Client Documents Root Path").TrimEnd('\\') + "\\CreditBureaux\\" ;

                    var fileName = summary.Enquiry_Id + ".pdf";

                    FileHandlingFactory.Create().SaveFile(xmlDoc.Root.Element("CC_PDF_RESULTS").Value.DecodeBase64ToByteArray().ToMemoryStream(), directory, fileName);

                    docMan.Add_Document(
                        new FileItem { 
                            CreatedOn_TimeStampUTC = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            FilePathOnServer = directory,
                            PrivateFileName = fileName,
                            PublicFileName = (Client.Person.Surname + Client.Person.NickName[0]) + "_" + fileName,
                            MimeType = "application/pdf"
                        },
                        docMan.FindOrCreate_ContextInstance(
                            docMan.Get_ContextClass("Client"),
                            new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                                {"ClientId",Client.Id.ToString()}
                            }),
                         new List<DocumentClass> { docMan.Get_DocumentClass("CreditBureaux enquiry") });
                    //xmlDoc.Root.Element("CC_PDF_RESULTS").Value
                    //.DecodeBase64ToByteArray()
                    //.SaveToFile(directory, summary.Enquiry_Id + ".pdf");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The stack trace to follow:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: s
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s]
>   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +14073970
>   SomeCompany.CreditBureaux.BLL.CreditBureauxLiveClient.RunEnquiry(Client
>   Client, String ResultType) +2270
>   SomeCompany.CrediScan.UI.Views.ClientController.CreditCheck(Int64 id)
>   +264    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +114    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +139
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   +112    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   +452    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +241
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +19
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: Your code has a bug so show us that code.

Comment: I don't think so.  It works perfectly on my dev environment.

Comment: The two environments obviously are not the same. Since we have no indication that it might be an infrastructure bug it's probably a code bug (like it is most of the time). Triggered by the different environment.

Comment: Even if this hunch is wrong there is not enough information here to diagnose the problem. At least post the full exception including stack.

Comment: OK, I have added the code and the stacktrace.  I can confirm that this issue is not caused by my production data (see points under the heading "More information on the production environment")